# How do I upload a compressed texture to Vulkan?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I'm interested in using a BC1 compressed image in Vulkan. There isn't any information I can find on how to do this. Do I have use my own code to encode/compress the pixels? Or does Vulkan do it itself? Help please?

Answer (score 2):

Uploading a compressed image is pretty straightforward. Fundamentally, it's no different from uploading data to a non-compressed image format. You get some data appropriate to the image format (compressed or uncompressed). You put it into some Vulkan device memory. And then you copy it into the image with a matching image format, probably one whose memory resides in device-local memory. If you can do this for uncompressed images, you can do it for compressed ones.

How you get compressed image *data* is not Vulkan's business. Vulkan isn't OpenGL; it exists solely to talk to the graphics device. Compressing image data is your job.

Comment: "You put it into some Vulkan device memory. And then you copy it ..." - If it's a host visible staging buffer it's not device memory, right? Not trying to be pedantic, just testing if my conception is sound. I mean, it's memory that the device has available to it, but not device memory... ummm, oh I'm confused.

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*If it's a host visible staging buffer it's not device memory, right?*" From the first line of the chapter titled "Device Memory": "Device memory is memory that is visible to the device — for example the contents of the image or buffer objects, which can be natively used by the device." You're probably thinking about "device local", but even device local memory can be host-visible.